# Hide/show ul li items that contain a word. But check only in a children of the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Markup: (lets asume that there are many childrens in the list, all with same markup)

```
<ul class="notifications messages inbox">   
                <li class=" unread">
                            <div class="avatar">
                                <a href="index.php?userid=94"><img alt="" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276073_662982570_5177619_n.jpg"> </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="txt">
                                <a class="userName" href="index.php?userid=94">Jose ignacio bustamante  <span class="date"> - 2012-09-07 13:49:59</span></a>
                                <div>
                                                                        <a href="messages.php?conversationid=94" class="msj"><span>Esque esto de querer cargar una conversación por defecto... como usuario no ...</span></a>
                                </div>      
                            </div>
                            <span data-id="442" class="close">X</span>          
                    </li>
```

So I am trying to filter this `<li>` elements depending on the .username tag value ( inside of it)

```
/* I have used this before, its a :contains modification to handle uppercase */
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
          return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
              .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
$('body').on('keyup','.filterFriends',function(){
                $('.inbox li').hide().filter(':icontains("'+this.value+'")').show();
                        /* How to apply this icontains selector to $('.inbox li').find('.userName') ?? */
});
```

This has a problem, i guess it checks in the whole li, and i dont really see how to select the .userName class within the filter() function..

Can anybody show me the light?

Comment: `.filter(function() {return $('a.userName:icontains("'+self.value+'")'), this);})`

Comment: It's in the context of `this`, so it will return any `li`'s that have an `a` element with the given text etc. The `self` variable is set outside the filters scope ie. above the hide/show line, and goes like `var self = this;`

Comment: Here's another option: http://jsfiddle.net/EeRvp/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('body').on('keyup','.filterFriends',function(){
    var li=$('.inbox li').hide();
    $('.userName',li).filter(':icontains("'+this.value+'")').parents('li').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('keyup','.filterFriends',function(){
    $('.inbox li')
        .hide()
        .find('.userName')
        .filter(':icontains("'+this.value+'")')
        .closest('.inbox li')
        .show();
});
```